# Reset GridView/ListView 's scroll position programatically (win store app)

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

My GridView re-populated when the user chooses ComboBox item. The problem starts when the user scroll the gridView somewhere to to the middle of the gridview and when he chooses different item in the comboBox, what happens is thee scroll looks like it went to the start, but now when you try to move a bit right or left you see that the scroll position updated and appears where it has been at the moment when the user chose differnt combobox item. In addition, although the scroll appears for a second in the beginning, you can see that for this sec the gridview shows the middle-r groups (it's a grouped grid view).
So As mentioned above I want to reset gridview scrool position (to the start position) after the gridview populated.

Here is the the gridview belongings:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridGames"
                      Grid.Row="3"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemClick="OnGameClick"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listView}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewSource}}"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                      ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                               Style="{StaticResource eaderStyle}"
                                               Text="{Binding Key}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <!--  <local:GroupHeader Width="800" Height="35" />  -->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,20,0" Orientation="Vertical" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
```

And this in the local resources:

```
<Style TargetType="GridView">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,10" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                        <ContentThemeTransition />
                        <ReorderThemeTransition />
                        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <!--
                <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                <ItemsPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            -->
        </Style>


<Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground"
                                       Fill="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                       Opacity="0" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              Margin="0,0,5,5"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                       StrokeDashOffset=".5"
                                       StrokeEndLineCap="Square" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                       StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                                       StrokeEndLineCap="Square" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you (re)populate the gridview? Are you setting it to empty before repopulating? That might help.

e.g. try adding this before you set the source for the gridview after the user selects the combobox item:

GridGames.ItemsSource = Nothing